# front usb wont mount harddrives, internal usb ports do

Tags: external-hdd, usb-drive

I have noticed something in my new build, i am using Ubuntu desktop newest version
my motherboard is the asus f1a75-m pro R2.0

with the usb ports in the back all my NTFS hard disks or usb sticks work fine,
but then.. when i put them in the front usb ports of my chassis (silverstone milo ml-03) they wont mount...

I have 2 usb 3.0 ports in front of the case connected with a internal usb 3.0 header. But i verified that the usb 3.0 ports on the back do mount the harddisk so it has nothing to do with usb 3.0 i think.

The strange thing is, my mouse works fine on the front usb ports. Every usb hardware piece seems to work except if it has any memory inside it :(

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does `dmesg` says something when you insert usb stick in the front panel port?
There are two different USB 3.0 controllers in your motherboard. Possible Ubuntu hasn't (currently) storage support for controller which refers to front panel ports.

From your MB specs:

```
AMD A75 FCH (Hudson D3) chipset : 4 x USB 3.0 port(s) (2 at back
panel, blue, 2 at mid-board)

ASMedia® USB 3.0 controller : 2 x USB 3.0 port(s) (2 at back panel,
blue)
```

Check the BIOS settings. Probably there are some, which allows to change the behaviour of your front panel ports.

Also, the problem may be in the too long USB cable (In the case with a harddrive).

[Additional reading](https://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/article/usb-cables-size-matters)

P.S. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: I just checked my bios. The one thing i saw was that usb 3.0 charging was disabled so i enabled it just in case.. still did not work. I really dont know what to do now <,<

There are not any settings that change usb 3,0 specific in the front. So i guess im stuck now.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey! i found out something.. My external HDD has 2 usb connections. Normally just one works fine. but now it did not, however when i connect both of them to both my front ports it works! so storage is enabled. but their is not enough power? What could be the problem of this? i cant stick with just putting 2 usb in because my usb stick also does not work..

Comment: What is your PSU? Does your USB stick work fine in both pairs of back panel ports? If it so, I suppose the problem is in bundle "PSU - length/quality of internal USB cabel" Try to run your PC with another PSU if you have such ability.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Ubuntu doesn't supply enough power to the front ports. I had a similar problem where a wifi dongle got low speed on the front ports and high speed on the back. It seems this is a driver issue because it works fine in Windows. I don't have a fix yet unfortunately.